# what is the alternative of `prompt $g` in cygwin

Tags: cygwin, command-prompt

In Windows, I can use `prompt $g` to hide the path and replace it with `>` in the command prompt as shown in the below picture,

[image]

This is extremely beneficial if the path of the current directory long. I'm looking for similar command for cygwin. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell's prompt is taken from the `$PS1` variable. If you want to show just `>`, set the variable to it

```
PS1='>'
```

It might be more convenient to use something like `\W` which displays the current directory name without path:

```
PS1='\W> '
```